# When I upload image through multer , I got image undefined error

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, multer

I am using it with **node and mysql with angular 5**.

```
        const express = require('express');
        const mysql = require('mysql');
        const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        const path = require('path');
        const cors = require('cors');
        const router = express.Router();
        const multer = require('multer');
        const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './assets/images/')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname)
        }
        });
        const fileFilter = (req, file, cb)=>{
        if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
            cb(null, true);
        }
        else{
            cb(null, false);
        }
        };
        upload = multer({
        storage: storage,
        limits:{
            filesize : 1024 * 1024 * 5
        },
        fileFilter : fileFilter
        });

        const app = express();

        //DATABASE CONNECTION
        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user:'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'inpblog',
        port: 8889
        });

        // ALLOW CROSS ORIGIN
        const corsOptions = {
        origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
        origin1: 'http://localhost:4202',
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
        };
        app.use(cors(corsOptions));
        app.use('./assets/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'upload')));

        const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
        const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });


        connection.connect(function(error){
        if(!!error){
            console.log("error - db not connected");
        }
        else{
            console.log("connected");
        }
        });
```

Here i define the code to upload a image in mysql database. through postman its upload a image in destination folder with multer middleware but when i upload a image through ng form its showing error in  console."image undefined" and submit the "c:/fakepath/image.jgg" in mysql.

**Here is the API to insert the post**

```
        app.post('/insertPost', upload.single('txt_blog_image'), jsonParser, (req, res) => {
        console.log("image: ", req.file); // working fine only with postman
        //console.log("rBody: ", req.body.txt_blog_image); // working fine only with Angular
        let blogFields = {
            post_author : req.body.txt_blog_author,
            post_image : req.body.txt_blog_image
        };
        let sql = 'INSERT INTO insdb SET ?';
        let query = connection.query(sql, blogFields, (err,result)=> {
            res.send('New Post  added...');
        });
        });

        // Get All Post
        app.get('/getallposts', (req, res) => {
        let sql = 'SELECT * FROM insdb';
        let query = connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(results);
            res.send(results);
        });
        });

        app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
        });

        app.listen(4202);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way.**

```
var path = require('path');
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './assets/images/')
   },
   filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    console.log(file)
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
   }
})
```

In your api :

```
app.post('/getallposts',upload.single("image") , function(req, res) {
   let sql = 'SELECT * FROM insdb';
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(results);
        res.send(results);
    });
})
```

From **Angular** side :

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append('image' , file);
```

Then `console` in server side , `req.files` to check file is coming or not ?

For more information and example please see this [link](https://evdokimovm.github.io/javascript/nodejs/expressjs/multer/2016/11/03/Upload-files-to-server-using-NodeJS-and-Multer-package-filter-upload-files-by-extension.html)

Comment: I tried to submit through postman and its working file but using through angular 5 its showing undefined.